# plsql function not supported in materialized view

Tags: sql, oracle12c, materialized-views

I want to create a materialized view (fast refresh). It contains some complex calculations that involve around 25+ tables. It's giving me error at PLSQL function which is written in where clause saying

> PLSQL function not supported by MV

Below is the MV I am trying to create. Please modify the syntax if I am missing something so it can allow the union and PLSQL function stuff with fast refresh.

**Note** I am not allowed to change the query by my management so please suggest me workaround to use this same query in the form of MV.

```
   create materialized view SAMPLE
ENABLE QUERY REWRITE
    refresh fast
    as
    select ms.employee_id,
           ms.sal_code code,
           'SALARY' Account_type,
           UPPER(sb.salary_breakup) Account_title,
           sb.account_code ACCOUNT_CODE,
           ('ADDITION') AMOUNT_TYPE,
           sb.pay_type PAY_TYPE,
           p.display_title PAY_TITLE,
           ms.salary AMOUNT,
           p.order_in_payroll,
           to_number((select order_by from payroll_account_title_org_wise
    where org_id=p.org_id and account_id=1) || substr(sb.sal_code,3,3)) Code_order,
           ms.month,
           sb.tax_exemption,
           sb.taxtation_type,
           'Y' INCLUDE_IN_MONTHLYTAX_INCOME,
           p.org_id
           from PAY_MONTHLY_SALARY ms,pay_salary_breakups sb,PAYROL_TYPE p
           where ms.sal_code=sb.sal_code
          and p.pay_type=sb.pay_type
           --order by sb.sal_code
    union
    -----ALLOWANCE PART
    select mad.employee_id,
           mad.ad_code code,
           ad.type Account_type,
           UPPER(ad.ad_name) Account_title,
           ad.account_code ACCOUNT_CODE,
           'ADDITION' AMOUNT_TYPE,
          ad.pay_type PAY_TYPE,
          p.display_title PAY_TITLE,
           mad.amount AMOUNT,
           p.order_in_payroll,
           to_number((select order_by from payroll_account_title_org_wise
    where org_id=p.org_id and account_id=2) || substr(mad.ad_code,3,3)) Code_order,
           mad.month,
           ad.tax_exemption,
           ad.taxtation_type,
           'Y' INCLUDE_IN_MONTHLYTAX_INCOME,
           p.org_id
           from Pay_Month_Allow_Ded mad,pay_allowance_deduction_setup ad,PAYROL_TYPE p
           where mad.ad_code=ad.ad_code
           and p.pay_type=ad.pay_type
           and ad.type ='ALLOWANCE'
           --order by ad.ad_code
    
    union
    -----DEDUCTION PART
    select mad.employee_id,
           mad.ad_code code,
           ad.type Account_type,
           UPPER(ad.ad_name) Account_title,
           ad.account_code ACCOUNT_CODE,
          'DEDUCTION' AMOUNT_TYPE,
          ad.pay_type PAY_TYPE,
          p.display_title PAY_TITLE,
           mad.amount AMOUNT,
           p.order_in_payroll,
           to_number((select order_by from payroll_account_title_org_wise
    where org_id=p.org_id and account_id=3) || substr(mad.ad_code,3,3)) Code_order,
           mad.month,
           ad.tax_exemption,
           ad.taxtation_type,
           'Y' INCLUDE_IN_MONTHLYTAX_INCOME,
           p.org_id
           from Pay_Month_Allow_Ded mad,pay_allowance_deduction_setup ad,PAYROL_TYPE p
           where mad.ad_code=ad.ad_code
           and p.pay_type=ad.pay_type
           and ad.type='DEDUCTION'
           --order by ad.ad_code
    
    union
    ---- FUNDS AND CONTRIBUTION PART
    select e.employee_id
    ,fcs.fc_code
    ,'FUNDS' Account_type
    ,UPPER(fct.fc_type_name) ACCOUNT_TITLE
    ,(case when fct.type='EMPLOYEE' then fcs.account_code_credit
           when fct.type='EMPLOYER' then fcs.account_code
             end) ACCOUNT_CODE
    ,(case when fct.type='EMPLOYEE' then 'DEDUCTION'
           when fct.type='EMPLOYER' then 'OTHERTAX'
             end) AMOUNT_TYPE
    ,pt.pay_type
    ,pt.display_title PAY_TITLE
    ,r.amount AMOUNT
    ,pt.order_in_payroll
    ,to_number((select order_by from payroll_account_title_org_wise
    where org_id=pt.org_id and account_id=4) || substr(fcs.fc_code,3,3)) Code_order
    ,r.month
    ,(case when fcs.TAX_EXEMPTION='Y' then fcs.tax_exemption
           when fcs.TAX_EXEMPTION='N' then fct.tax_exemption
             end) TAX_EXEMPTION,
            fcs.taxtation_type,
           'Y' INCLUDE_IN_MONTHLYTAX_INCOME,
           pt.org_id
    from
    hr_employee_info e
    ,fund_contribution_records r
    ,fund_contributions_type fct
    ,fund_contributions_setup fcs
    ,payrol_type pt
    where e.employee_id=r.employee_id
    and r.contribution_type_id=fct.contribution_type_id
    and r.fc_code=fcs.fc_code
    and fct.fc_code=fcs.fc_code
    and fct.payroll_type=pt.pay_type
    
    union
    ----- ATTENDACE DATA PART
    select
    pmt.employee_id
    ,att.att_code
    ,'ATTENDANCE' Account_type
    ,UPPER(att.attendace_type) ACCOUNT_TITLE
    ,NULL ACCOUNT_CODE
    ,'ZERO' AMOUNT_TYPE
    ,pt.pay_type
    ,pt.display_title PAY_TITLE
    ,pmt.attendance_days AMOUNT
    ,pt.order_in_payroll
    ,to_number((select order_by from payroll_account_title_org_wise
    where org_id=pt.org_id and account_id=5) || substr(att.att_code,3,3)) Code_order
    ,pmt.month
    ,'Y' TAX_EXEMPTION
    ,'NONE' taxtation_type
    ,'N' INCLUDE_IN_MONTHLYTAX_INCOME
    ,       pt.org_id
    from att_attendance_seup att
    ,pay_monthly_attendance pmt
    ,payrol_type pt
    where att.att_code=pmt.att_code
    and pt.pay_type=att.pay_type
    and pt.org_id=att.org_id
    
    /*union
    
    ---- TARGET DATA PART
    
    select
    pmt.employee_id
    ,pts.ta_code CODE
    ,UPPER(pts.target_name) ACCOUNT_TITLE
    ,'ZERO' AMOUNT_TYPE
    ,pt.pay_type
    ,pt.display_title PAY_TITLE
    ,pmt.value AMOUNT
    ,pt.order_in_payroll
    ,to_number(5 || substr(pts.ta_code,4,1)) Code_order
    ,pmt.month
    ,'Y' TAX_EXEMPTION,
           pt.org_id
    from
    pay_monthly_targets pmt
    ,pay_target_setup pts
    ,payrol_type pt
    where pts.ta_code=pmt.ta_code
    and pt.pay_type=pts.pay_type*/
    
    union
    
    ----LOAN DISBURSEMENT PART
    
    
    select
    pmld.employee_id
    ,plns.ln_code code
    ,'LOAN DISBURSEMENT' Account_type
    ,UPPER(plns.loan_name) ACCOUNT_TITLE
    ,plns.account_code ACCOUNT_CODE
    ,'ADDITION' AMOUNT_TYPE
    ,pt.pay_type
    ,pt.display_title PAY_TITLE
    ,pmld.amount
    ,pt.order_in_payroll
    ,to_number((select order_by from payroll_account_title_org_wise
    where org_id=pt.org_id and account_id=6) || substr(plns.ln_code,3,3)) Code_order
    ,pmld.month
    ,'Y' tax_exemption
    ,plns.taxtation_type
    ,'N' INCLUDE_IN_MONTHLYTAX_INCOME
    ,       pt.org_id
    from
    PAY_LOAN_SETUP plns
    ,pay_loan_monthly_disbursement pmld
    ,payrol_type pt
    where plns.ln_code=pmld.ln_code
    and plns.pay_type_disburse=pt.pay_type
    
    union
    
    ------- LOAN INSTALLMENTS PART
    select
    peld.employee_id
    ,plns.ln_code code
    ,'LOAN INSTALLMENT' Account_type
    ,UPPER(plns.loan_name || '(I)') ACCOUNT_TITLE
    ,plns.account_code_installment ACCOUNT_CODE
    ,'DEDUCTION' AMOUNT_TYPE
    ,pt.pay_type
    ,pt.display_title PAY_TITLE
    ,plei.amount amount
    ,pt.order_in_payroll
    ,to_number((select order_by from payroll_account_title_org_wise
    where org_id=pt.org_id and account_id=7) || substr(plns.ln_code,3,3)) Code_order
    ,plei.month
    ,'Y' tax_exemption
    ,plns.taxtation_type
    ,'N' INCLUDE_IN_MONTHLYTAX_INCOME
    ,       pt.org_id
    from
    PAY_LOAN_SETUP plns
    ,PAY_EMP_LOAN_DISBURSEMENT peld
    ,PAY_EMP_LOAN_INSTALMENTS plei
    ,payrol_type pt
    where plns.ln_code=peld.ln_code
    and peld.loan_id=plei.loan_id
    and plns.pay_type=pt.pay_type
    and pt.org_id=plns.org_id
    
    
    -----LOAN MARKUP
    union
    
    select
    peld.employee_id
    ,plns.ln_code code
    ,'LOAN MARKUP' Account_type
    ,UPPER(plns.loan_name || '(M)') ACCOUNT_TITLE
    ,plns.account_code_markup ACCOUNT_CODE
    ,'DEDUCTION' AMOUNT_TYPE
    ,pt.pay_type
    ,pt.display_title PAY_TITLE
    ,plei.benchmark_taken amount
    ,pt.order_in_payroll
    ,to_number((select order_by from payroll_account_title_org_wise
    where org_id=pt.org_id and account_id=8) || substr(plns.ln_code,3,3)) Code_order
    ,plei.month
    ,'Y' tax_exemption
    ,plns.taxtation_type
    ,'N' INCLUDE_IN_MONTHLYTAX_INCOME
    ,       pt.org_id
    from
    PAY_LOAN_SETUP plns
    ,PAY_EMP_LOAN_DISBURSEMENT peld
    ,PAY_EMP_LOAN_INSTALMENTS plei
    ,payrol_type pt
    where plns.ln_code=peld.ln_code
    and peld.loan_id=plei.loan_id
    and plns.pay_type=pt.pay_type
    
    --------REIMBURSEMENT PART
    
    union
    
    select
    hrc.employee_id
    ,hrs.re_code CODE
    ,'REIMBURSEMENT' Account_type
    ,UPPER(hrs.reimbursement_name) ACCOUNT_TITLE
    ,hrs.account_code ACCOUNT_CODE
    ,'ADDITION' AMOUNT_TYPE
    ,pt.pay_type
    ,pt.display_title PAY_TITLE
    ,hrc.amount
    ,pt.order_in_payroll
    ,to_number((select order_by from payroll_account_title_org_wise
    where org_id=pt.org_id and account_id=9) || substr(hrs.re_code,3,3)) Code_order
    ,hrc.month
    ,hrs.tax_exemption
    ,hrs.taxtation_type
    ,'Y' INCLUDE_IN_MONTHLYTAX_INCOME
    ,       pt.org_id
    from
    hr_reimbursement_setup hrs
    ,pay_monthly_reimbursement hrc
    ,payrol_type pt
    ,hr_employee_info e
    where hrs.re_code=hrc.re_code
    and hrc.employee_id=e.employee_id
    and hrs.pay_type=pt.pay_type
    
    --------OTHER INCOME TAX PART
    
    
    union
    
    select d.employee_id
    ,to_char('OT'||lpad(d.itax_other_id,3,000)) CODE
    ,'OTHER TAXABLE' Account_type
    ,UPPER(s.name || '(OT)') ACCOUNT_TITLE
    ,NULL ACCOUNT_CODE
    ,'OTHERTAX' AMOUNT_TYPE
    ,pt.pay_type
    ,pt.display_title PAY_TITLE
    ,(case when s.type='ADDITION' then i.amount
           when s.type='EXEMPTION' then i.amount*-1
             end) Amount
    ,pt.order_in_payroll
    ,to_number((select order_by from payroll_account_title_org_wise
    where org_id=pt.org_id and account_id=10) || lpad(d.itax_other_id,3,000)) CODE_ORDER
    ,i.month
    ,'N' TAX_EXEMPTION
    ,s.taxtation_type
    ,s.include_in_mothly_income  INCLUDE_IN_MONTHLYTAX_INCOME
    ,i.org_id
    from
    PAY_MONTHLY_OTHER_TAX_INCOME i
    ,ITAX_DECLARE_OTHER_EMP_INCOME d
    ,ITAX_OTHER_INCOME_SETUP s
    ,payrol_type pt
    where i.org_id=s.org_id
    and d.org_id=s.org_id
    and i.itax_declare_id=d.itax_declare_id
    and s.itax_other_id=d.itax_other_id
    and s.pay_type=pt.pay_type
    and s.org_id=pt.org_id
    
    -----TAXABLE INCOME(just to show)
    
    union
    
    select
    i.employee_id
    ,t.tx_code CODE
    ,'TAXABLE INCOME' Account_type
    ,'TAXABLE INCOME' ACCOUNT_TITLE
    ,NULL ACCOUNT_CODE
    ,'ZERO' AMOUNT_TYPE
    ,pt.pay_type
    ,pt.display_title PAY_TITLE
    , sum(i.amount) amount
    ,pt.order_in_payroll
    ,to_number((select order_by from payroll_account_title_org_wise
    where org_id=i.org_id and account_id=11) || substr(t.tx_code,3,3)) Code_order
    ,i.month
    ,'Y' TAX_EXEMPTION
    ,'NONE' taxtation_type
    ,'N' INCLUDE_IN_MONTHLYTAX_INCOME
    ,i.org_id
    from
    TAX_CODE_REGIONS t
    ,PAY_EMP_MONTHLY_TAXABLE_INCOME i
    ,payrol_type pt
    where t.tx_code=i.tx_code
    and i.INCLUDE_IN_MOTHLY_INCOME='Y'
    --and t.pay_type=pt.pay_type
    and pt.pay_type=Default_Value.GET_SYSTEM_DEFAULT('TXPAYTYPE',i.org_id)
    group by i.employee_id,t.tx_code,pt.pay_type,pt.display_title,pt.order_in_payroll,i.month,i.org_id
    
    
    
    --------Income Tax Part
    
    union
    
    
    select
    i.employee_id
    ,t.tx_code CODE
    ,'INCOME TAX' Account_type
    ,'INCOME TAX' ACCOUNT_TITLE
    ,DEFAULT_VALUE.GET_SYSTEM_DEFAULT('ITAC',i.org_id) ACCOUNT_CODE
    ,'DEDUCTION' AMOUNT_TYPE
    ,pt.pay_type
    ,pt.display_title PAY_TITLE
    ,i.amount amount
    ,pt.order_in_payroll
    ,to_number((select order_by from payroll_account_title_org_wise
    where org_id=pt.org_id and account_id=12) || substr(t.tx_code,3,3)) Code_order
    ,i.month
    ,'Y' TAX_EXEMPTION
    ,'NONE' taxtation_type
    ,'N' INCLUDE_IN_MONTHLYTAX_INCOME
    ,i.org_id
    from
    TAX_CODE_REGIONS t
    ,pay_monthly_itax i
    ,payrol_type pt
    where t.tx_code=i.tx_code
    --and t.pay_type=pt.pay_type
    and pt.pay_type=Default_Value.GET_SYSTEM_DEFAULT('TXPAYTYPE',i.org_id)
    
    
    
    -----GRATUITY PART(only for report purpose)
    
    union
    
    select
    p.employee_id
    ,to_char('GP'||lpad(p.gratuity_id,3,000)) CODE
    ,'GRATUITY' Account_type
    ,UPPER(gs.name) ACCOUNT_TITLE
    ,gs.account_code ACCOUNT_CODE
    ,'ZERO' AMOUNT_TYPE
    ,gs.pay_type
    ,pt.display_title PAY_TITLE
    ,p.amount
    ,pt.order_in_payroll
    ,to_number((select order_by from payroll_account_title_org_wise
    where org_id=pt.org_id and account_id=13) || lpad(p.gratuity_id,3,000)) CODE_ORDER
    ,p.month
    ,'Y' TAX_EXEMPTION
    ,'NONE' taxtation_type
    ,'N' INCLUDE_IN_MONTHLYTAX_INCOME
    ,pt.org_id
    from
    HR_GRATUITY_MONTHLY_ACCRUALS p,
    HR_GRATUITY_SETUP gs,
    payrol_type pt
    where p.gratuity_id=gs.gratuity_id
    and p.org_id=gs.org_id
    and gs.pay_type=pt.pay_type
    and p.org_id=pt.org_id
    
    ---------LEAVE ENCASHMENT PART
    
    union
    
    select
    LED.Employee_Id
    ,'LE'||lpad(lt.leave_type_id,3,0) CODE
    ,'ALLOWANCE' ACCOUNT_TYPE
    ,UPPER(lt.leave_name) ACCOUNT_TITLE
    ,null ACCOUNT_CODE
    ,'ADDITION' AMOUNT_TYPE
    ,pt.pay_type
    ,pt.display_title PAY_TITLE
    ,LED.Amount
    ,pt.order_in_payroll
    ,to_number((select order_by from payroll_account_title_org_wise
    where org_id=pt.org_id and account_id=2)||lpad(lt.leave_type_id,3,0)) CODE_ORDER
    ,LED.Month
    ,'N' TAX_EXEMPTION
    ,'VARIABLE' TAXTATION_TYPE
    ,'Y' INCLUDE_IN_MONTHLYTAX_INCOME
    ,LED.Org_Id
    from
    HR_LEAVE_ENCASHMENT_DISBRSE LED
    ,Hr_Leave_Type lt
    ,(select max(pt.order_in_payroll) order_in_payroll,pt.org_id from Payrol_Type pt group by pt.org_id) pt_a
    ,Payrol_Type pt
    where LED.Leave_Type_Id=lt.leave_type_id
    and LED.Org_Id=lt.org_id
    and LED.Org_Id=pt_a.org_id
    and pt_a.org_id=pt.org_id
    and pt_a.order_in_payroll=pt.order_in_payroll
    
    ------Generate Fake Lines For every Employee against pay_type
    
    union
    
    select
    e.employee_id
    ,'FAKE' CODE
    ,pt.display_title Account_type
    ,'FAKE' ACCOUNT_TITLE
    ,pt.account_code ACCOUNT_CODE
    ,'ZERO' AMOUNT_TYPE
    ,pt.pay_type
    ,pt.display_title PAY_TITLE
    ,0 AMOUNT
    ,pt.order_in_payroll
    ,99991 CODE_ORDER
    ,pi.month
    ,'Y' TAX_EXEMPTION
    ,'NONE' taxtation_type
    ,'N' INCLUDE_IN_MONTHLYTAX_INCOME
    ,pi.org_id
    from
    PAY_MONTHLY_PROCESS_INFO pi
    ,hr_employee_info e
    ,payrol_type pt
    where pi.org_id=e.org_id
    and pi.org_id=pt.org_id
    and pi.month>=e.join_date;
```

Comment: If you can't change the query, you can't create a fast-refreshable materialized view.  You can go through the documentation on the restrictions on a fast-refreshable materialized view https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/basicmv.htm#i1007007 but your query violates several of them.  If may be possible to modify the query to become fast-refreshable but that will involve changing the query which you've said isn't possible.

Comment: As explained by Justin cave you have to re-think on your query first. One option would be creating nested materialized views with first refresh and on top of that you build others. And also explore the mv_capabilities_table (exact name not sure) to check capability of a materialized view for fast refresh after you created it as sometimes even though the materialized view is created and still it won't be capable of fast refresh.